Overriding implementation of a library Component
The problem (Angular 14)
I want to override a function from a library Component (Angular Material) without re-implementing the whole component.
The idea
My thinking is inspired by one of the examples from MatPaginator documentation.
They override the default implementation of the getRangeLabel function from MatPaginatorIntl and then they provide the new implementation in the Component using the providers field:
@Injectable()
export class MyCustomPaginatorIntl implements MatPaginatorIntl {
  getRangeLabel(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string {
    if (length === 0) {
      return $localize`Page 1 of 1`;
    }
    const amountPages = Math.ceil(length / pageSize);
    return $localize`Page ${page + 1} of ${amountPages}`;
  }
}

@Component({
  providers: [{provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: MyCustomPaginatorIntl}],
})
export class PaginatorIntlExample {}

Naturally I was wondering if I can do the same for the MatPaginator Component itself:
@Injectable()
export class MyCustomPaginatorComponent extends MatPaginator {
  override hasNextPage(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

@Component({
  providers: [{provide: MatPaginator , useClass: MyCustomPaginatorComponent}],
})
export class PaginatorIntlExample {}

But this doesn't work.
Similar topics
I understand that MatPaginatorIntl is directly injected into MatPaginator's constructor, while MatPaginator is not Injectable itself but rather a Component. But I was wondering if there is any way to override a function from MatPaginator without re-implementing the template.
I found a similar question but I want to extend the behaviour of MatPaginator rather than re-implementing the whole new Component with the same selector.
In another post they are accessing MatPaginator with ViewChild but I want to avoid this approach because I will need this in a generic Component which most of the time uses default MatPaginator but in a special case uses the custom implementation.
Probably the best solution would be to use content projection but then I would need to change all of the already existing components that use this generic component and since this is a special case it also doesn't make a lot of sense.
TL;DR;
I want to override a function from MatPaginator for just one module. How can I do that?

One approach to "override" is create a Directive. A directive makes that one "HTML tag" becomes a "super tag".
As you are going to apply this directive in a mat-paginator, you can use the constructor to get it using @Host
@Directive({
  selector:'[super-paginator]',
  standalone:true,
  
})
export class SuperDirective
{
  constructor(@Host() paginator:MatPaginator)
  {
      paginator.hasNextPage=(): boolean=>{
        return true;
      }
  }
}

And use
<mat-paginator super-paginator [length]="100" ....></mat-paginator>

NOTE: Don't forget import the directive
See stackblitz
Update if we have a component that include a mat-paginator and only in a few of them we can override the function we can use an input
@Input() override:boolean=false;

<mat-paginator [super-paginator]="override" [length]="100" ....></mat-paginator>

And our directive like
@Directive({
  selector:'[super-paginator]',
  standalone:true,

})
export class SuperDirective
{
  @Input('super-paginator') set _(value){
     if (value)
     {
         this.paginator.hasNextPage=(): boolean=>{
            return true;
         }
     }
  }
  //see that we use "private"
  constructor(@Host() private paginator:MatPaginator){}


At first glance this seemed to work nicely but after testing this code I came to realize that his might not be the best way. It directly overrides the property of MatPaginator which means that every component that uses my Generic component will now also run this code instead of the default. Why? Moving from one page to another doesn't trigger re-rendering of the component and therefore doesn't return MatPaginator to the default value leaving it with the new value. As I already stated, the behaviour for the existing components should stay the same.

@Sulejman, Only the components that have the "directive" super-paginator override the function. Always can use an @Input to override or not the function. I update the answer.

Already did that, but that doesn't fix the issue. Let's say, I first go on a page that should not override. The if statement will fail and the function stays the same. Then I go on another one where it does override, still good so far because it works how it should on this page. Finally, I go back to the first one. Even though the if statement will fail again and won't override the function, it makes no difference because the function was overwritten when I went on a second page, and there was nothing to reset this function after that. That's what I was referring to by not re-rendering.
